# Managing state of multiple list item with ID in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having multiple list item in my DOM whenever I click a list item I call the API for that particular item and store it in my Redux store and when I click another item in DOM I add it to my array in redux store.

The problem I am facing is when I click the same list item again I don't want to hit the API again I want to show data for that particular list item already stored in my redux store how should I do it?

My Reducer Code

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    fareRules: [],
    error: false
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SET_FARE_RULES:
            return {
                ...state,
                fareRules: [
                    ...state.fareRules,
                    {
                        id: action.id,
                        rules: action.fareRules[0][0]
                    }
                ]
            }
        case actionTypes.GET_FARE_RULES_FAILED:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: true
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Can you show us what kind of structure `fareRules` has? With an example maybe? I'd follow what @Rahamin said below, probably in your `case actionTypes.SET_FARE_RULES` section

Answer (score 1):

In your handler for handling a click on the item, you need to check if the fare rules for that item already exist in the store (your component needs to have access to the store).

If the fare rules for that item do no exist, add them (fire the relevant action), otherwise display them.

Comment: Wouldn't it slow down the speed of my application?

Comment: The time that passes from the monent a user decides to click on sn itdm, to the time he clucjs, will take much more than doing many such checks.

Comment: Sory for the typos :)